# R programming: Is it possible to declare return or parameter types of functions?

Tags: r, function, types

Is it possible to declare the return type or the parameter types of functions in R?

For example, given the following function

```
probability_k_correct = function(k) {
    # ... calculate probability
    return (0.1 * k)
}
```

I'd like to make it obvious for the reader that `k` must be an `integer`, `numeric`, `complex` or some other type and that the function returns, for example, a `numeric`.

If it's not possible, are there any tools (like precompilers) that add this functionality?

Comment: Something like `stopifnot(is.numeric(k) | is.numeric(k) | is.integer(k))`?

Comment: @jay.sf Actually I'm looking for something similar to _type hints_ in Python, where you just have to look at the function declaration. Something like `function(k: integer) -> numeric`.

Comment: No. 12345678901

Comment: Type hints do not exist in R

Answer (score 18, accepted):

https://github.com/jimhester/types or
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/types/

You can add type annotations to functions using the package below. These will be printed if you print the function closure, and are also supported with function tooltips in RStudio.

Annotated return types will not show up in the function auto-completion, but you can print the function closure to see them.

```
#devtools::install_github('jimhester/types')
# or install.packages("types")
library(types)

myadd <- function( x = ? numeric, y = ? numeric) {
  (x + y) ? numeric
}
myadd()


myadd2 <- function( x = ? numeric ? integer, y = ? numeric) {
  x + y
}
```

[image]

Comment: Not completely on-topic (no rstudio tag) but upvote.

Comment: It works in Rgui as well, in that if you print the function closure you will see the type hints.

Comment: sadly it kills the "missing argument check" you can run it now as `myadd()` and it will fail somewhere inside the function using x or y.